# Nested for loop is really slow for query set traversal in Django

Tags: python, django, performance, django-models

I have two models named **machine** and **performance**,

```
class machine(models.Model):
    machine_type = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=10)
    machine_no = models.IntegerField(null=True)    
    machine_name = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=255)
    machine_sis = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=255)
    store_code = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Performance(models.Model):
    machine_no = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    power = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    store_code = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

For each **Machine**, there are multiple fields of **in Performance Model** and I have to find the count of **Performance Model's** rows in the db which have power = some_integer. Here is what my view looks like:

```
machines = machine.objects.filter(machine_type="G",machine_sis="919")
```

Let's say `machine.count()` sometimes is 100. For each of this machine I need to calculate the number of machines which have power = 100 in performance model. So what I did first was but was really slow:

```
for obj in machines:
    print performance.objects.filter(machine_no=obj.machine_no,power=100).count()
```

My second approach was faster than the first approach:

```
for obj in machines:
    data = performance.objects.filter(machine_no=obj.machine_no,power=100)
    counter = 0
    for p in data: # ***** lets say this loop is called star-loop
        if p.power == 100:
            counter +=1
```

My problem is that the speed is really slow when I have to check 100 machines in Performance model whose power = something.

I am not using foreign key in **Performance Model** because the actual architecture is more complex and I can't use machine number or anything as foreign key because when identifying each machine uniquely I need multiple columns of machine.

Also, this project is working in production and I can't take much chance. I am using Django 1.11, Python 2.7 and postresql rds instance. I have increased the network performance buy renting a better instance from aws.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you didn't use m2m between `Machine` and `Performance` model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the counting and filtering on the Python side:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(performance.objects.filter(power=100).
            values_list('machine_no', flat=True))


m = machine.objects.filter(machine_type="G",machine_sis="919")
    .values_list('machine_no', flat=True)

result = sum(v for k,v in c.items() if k in m)
```

---

> what if i need power = 100 and also separate list of machines with
>   power = 99 ? do i have to use two separate Counter() functions with
>   the query ?

No, just add the filter to the same query, using a [`Q` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects), then calculate two different results, like this:

```
from collections import Counter
from django.db.models import Q

c = Counter(performance.objects.filter(power=100 | Q(power=99)).
            values_list('machine_no', 'power'))

m = machine.objects.filter(machine_type="G",machine_sis="919")
    .values_list('machine_no', flat=True)

result_100 = sum(v for k,v in c.items() if k[0] in m and k[1] = 100)
result_99  = sum(v for k,v in c.items() if k[0] in m and k[1] = 99)
```

Comment: what if i need power = 100 and also separate list of machines with power = 99 ? do i have to use two separate Counter() functions with the query ? If this is the case then, one counter is taking around .75 secs for avg case and when i use two then it takes 1.5 secs.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a case of the N+1 Select porblem. You can do the following to reduce query count:

```
machines = machine.objects.filter(machine_type="G",machine_sis="919")
machine_nos = machine.values_list('machine_no', flat=True)
performance = performance.objects.filter(machine_no__in=machine_nos, power=100)
```

This reduces number of queries to a maximum of three

Answer (score 0):

You can use raw queries. It maybe like this. Please update to use exactly your database table name.

```
 machine.objects.raw(select * from machine as b
      join (select count(id), machine_no from performance where power=100 
      group by machine_no) as a
      on b.id = a.machine_no
      where b.machine_type="G" and b.machine_sis="919")
```